# $\left|\sin(x)\right|$ derivative at $\pi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a function, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      e^{x^2}-2 & x< 0 \\
x^3+x-1 & 0\leq x \leq 1 \\ 
     \left|\sin(x)\right|  & x>1. 
   \end{cases}$$

Check if $f$ is continuous and differentiable at $a$, when $a=0,1,\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, find $f'(a)$.

**What I've been doing:**

I found that:

- $f$ is continuous at $0$ but not differentiable.
- $f$ is not continuous at $1$ so it's not differentiable.

And then I thought that $f$ was differentiable at $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because $f$ is continuous at $(1, +\infty)$ ($\left|\sin(x)\right|$), so I looked for:

1. $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\left|\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\right|=0$ (by the solution my prof gave me this is correct).
2. $f'(\pi)=\left|\cos(\pi)\right|=-1$ Now this is wrong. The solution they gave me says that $f$ is not differentiable at $\pi$, and I'm really lost. Why is it differentiable at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and not $\pi$?

Comment: I've added an answer, but I noticed another error you made. $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Sorry!! I made a typo, it was $e^{x^2}-2$ when $x<0$

Comment: I suggest you graph $y = |\sin x|$ that will give you some intuition on what is happening at $\pi$ then consider $\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {|\sin (\pi+h)| - |\sin \pi|}{h}$ and  $\lim_\limits{h\to 0^-} \frac {|\sin (\pi+h)| - \sin \pi}{h}$  Are they equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, $|\sin x|$ is not differentiable at $x=\pi$ because the graph comes to a sharp corner there.

To make this reasoning rigorous, set $f(x)=|\sin x|$ and look at the difference quotient

$$\frac{f(\pi+h)-f(\pi)}{h}=\frac{|\sin(\pi+h)|}{h}$$

When $h\to0^{+}$, the difference quotient is $-\frac{1}{h}\sin(\pi+h)=\frac{1}{h}(\sin h)$, which tends to $1$.

But when $h\to0^{-}$, the difference quotient is $\frac{1}{h}\sin(\pi+h)=-\frac{1}{h}(\sin h)$, which tends to $-1$.

Therefore the two-sided limit of the difference quotient as $h\to 0$ does not exist.

So $f$ is not differentiable at $x=\pi$.

---

Note that my answer does *not* look at the limit of $f'$. It looks at the limit of the difference quotient, working directly from the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

- $f$ behaves like $\sin(x)$ around $\frac{\pi}{2}$. It is differentiable.
- $f$ behaves like $\sin(x)$ on the left of $\pi$ but it behaves like $-\sin(x)$ on the right.  We have to be more careful.
- $f(\pi)=0$.
- $\lim_{x \to \pi^-} \frac{f(x)-f(\pi)}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x \to \pi^-} \frac{f(x)-0}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x \to \pi^-} \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(\pi)}{x-\pi}=\cos(\pi)=-1$
- $\lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{f(x)-f(\pi)}{x-\pi}=\lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{-\sin x-0}{x-\pi}=-\lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x-\pi}=-\lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(\pi)}{x-\pi}=-\cos(\pi)=1$

Hopefully this picture can help you, notice where the kink occurs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*hint:*

A derivative is defined by a limit:
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} 
$$

As any limit, you must check that this limit does not depend on the path you use to compute it

In $\mathbb{R}$, only two paths are possibles: coming from the left or coming from the right, hence to prove derivability at $x$ you must check that 
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0_+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0_-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}  
$$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is indeed discontinuous at $x=1$.

Then from the function definition,

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 
      2xe^{x^2} & x< 0 \\
3x^2+1 & 0<x <1 \\ 
     \cos(x)  & 1<x<\pi 
     \\-\cos(x)  & \pi<x. 
   \end{cases}$$

We have mismatches between derivatives on the left and on the right at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$.

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but... the mere argument "$f'$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=a$, therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $x=a$" requires Darboux's theorem. The easier argument, which avoids killing a fly with a sledgerhammer, is simply to point out that the (two-sided) limit of the difference quotient does not exist.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: as you can see, I have *not* discussed differentiability at $x=1$. But a jump is never differentiable.

Comment: The question from OP is why $f$ isn’t differentiable at $\pi$. I agree you didn’t comment *explicitly* on differentiability at $\pi$. But the only way to read your post as an *answer to the question* is to read it as saying a jump in $f’$ implies non-differentiability in $f$. Otherwise your post just doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: the question is about differentiability at $\pi$.

Comment: Yes. That’s what I said.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: come on, if the left and right limits differ, there is no limit. Leave Darboux in peace.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the interval $[1, \pi]$, we have $f(x) = |\sin(x)| = \sin(x)$ because $\sin(x) \geq 0$. However, for $x \in [\pi, 2 \pi]$, we have $f(x) = -\sin(x)$ because $\sin(x) \leq 0$. Therefore,
$$ \lim_{x \to \pi^{-}} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to \pi{-}} \cos(x) = -1$$
and
$$ \lim_{x \to \pi^{+}} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to \pi^{+}} (-\cos(x)) = 1$$
Hence, $f$ is not differentiable at $x = \pi$.

Comment: This argument is not quite right, or at least is it not complete. For that "hence" to work, you need to explicitly invoke the theorem saying that if the one-sided limits of $f'$ exist but disagree as $x\to a$, then $f$ can't be differentiable at $a$.

Comment: To repair, see, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87927/interpreting-the-significance-of-darbouxs-theorem

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how to derivative behaves near $\pi$. To make things simple, we can regard the function as $sin(x)$ at the left neighborhood of $\pi$ and as $-sin(x)$ at the right neighborhood of $\pi$ (and as $0$ at $x=\pi$).

This means that the derivative on the left side of the point is $cos(x)$ and on the right side of the point is $-cos(x)$. As $x$ approaches $\pi$ from the left, the derivative approaches $cos(\pi)=-1$. As $x$ approaches $\pi$ from the right, the derivative approaches $-cos(\pi)$=1. This is a contradiction to Darboux's theorem (can you explain why?), therefore the derivative does not exists at $x=\pi$.

You can also show this directly using the definition of the derivative, but I believe this explanation is sufficient.

Comment: This answer just repeats the argument in Mark's answer. As I commented there, the reasoning is incomplete. You must invoke the heavier-duty theorem that a derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity.

Comment: You're right, the explanation wasn't completely precise. I changed it a bit, hope it's better now (it's still more of an explanation than a proof).

Answer (score -1):

Be carefull with absolute values. You have the function $\sin(x)$ changing sign at $\pi$, so its absolute value can have a "sharp" non-differentiable point at $\pi$. That is what is happening.

You have
$$|sin(x)|=\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\sin(x)\text{, for }x\leq\pi \\
-\sin(x)\text{, for }x\geq\pi
\end{array}\right. $$

That means that **in a neighbourhood of $\pi$** it is  $\frac{d|sin(x)|}{dx}\neq|cos(x)|=cos(x)$, but rather
$$\frac{d|sin(x)|}{dx}=
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\cos(x)\text{, for }x\leq\pi \\
-\cos(x)\text{, for }x\geq\pi
\end{array}\right.$$
wich is not continuous at $\pi$

Comment: Yet again, for this argument to work, you must invoke the theorem that derivatives cannot have jump discontinuities. That is a *non-trivial* theorem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87927/interpreting-the-significance-of-darbouxs-theorem